# Combine blurred still frames from GIF to form crisp still

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

When watching a `GIF`, the image seems to be crisp, as the animation is moving along quite quickly.  If you were to analyze the `GIF` frame by frame, you'd notice that each image is rather blurry.

I'm wondering if it is possible to combine frames near to each other using some kind of filtering in Photoshop to produce one clear still image?

Comment: That would depend on the `GIF`.

Comment: Sarcasm aside, the answer could be yes, depending on `GIF` in question. Was it created from a video? Is it of a static scene? Does it require stabilization?

Answer (score 2):

The process itself is called `interpolation` and probably for video, `frame interpolation`. Regarding Photoshop's ability to do this, I am unsure.